# NSNotificationCenter: Removing an Observer in Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view controller with a button. When the button is pressed it adds an observer, like so:

```
func buttonPress(sender:UIButton){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("buttonPressEvent", object:nil, queue:nil, usingBlock:{(notif) -> Void in
        // code
    })
}
```

When I dismiss this view controller, and then return to it and press the button the `//code` is executed twice. If I go away and come back again the `//code` is executed three times, and so on.

What I want to do is to remove the Observer before I add it again, so this code doesn't execute twice. [Ive gone through the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:) and Ive added this line of code just above where I add the Observer:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:"buttonPressEvent", object:nil)
```

But this isnt working.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you use the 'blocks' based approach to observing notifications then `self` isn't in fact the observer. The function returns an object which acts as the observer:

```
func addObserverForName(_ name: String?,
                 object obj: AnyObject?,
                  queue queue: NSOperationQueue?,
             usingBlock block: (NSNotification!) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol
```

You need to keep a reference to this returned object and pass it in as the observer when you call `removeObserver`

It's explained well in the Apple Doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:)

Answer (score -1):

Implemented it like this, seems to be working fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()    
       AddScreenShotNotification() 
}

 func AddScreenShotNotification() {

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
           self,
            selector: #selector(MyViewController.ScreenShotTaken),
            name: UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
            object: nil)
}

func ScreenShotTaken()
    {        
 // do something     
    }

 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)    
    }
```